# playwright python iterating through HTML table

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, playwright-python

Currently working with data in a HTML table on a webpage that looks like this:

[image]

I have the following python code using playwright:

```py
from config import CLINK_ID, CSA_PWD, MY_URL
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(MY_URL)
    page.fill('input#username', CLINK_ID)
    page.fill('input#password', CSA_PWD)
    page.click('button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block')
    page.wait_for_load_state()
    page.hover('body > div:nth-child(1) > div.top-menu > div > nav > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a')
    page.click('body > div:nth-child(1) > div.top-menu > div > nav > ul > li:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a') # GWL compare
    page.wait_for_load_state()
    page.select_option('#listTable_length > label > select', value="-1") # show all entries
    page.wait_for_load_state(timeout=0)
    table = page.locator('//*[@id="listTable"]')
    row = (table.locator('tr'))
    print(row.locator('td').all_text_contents())
```

expecting to receive console output with table contents. But the output is:
[image]
I'm pretty sure that the date is present because I receive expected results while using selenium with the following code:

```py
from config import CLINK_ID, CSA_PWD, MY_URL
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\BF6141\\Documents\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
url = MY_URL
driver.get(url=url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(CLINK_ID)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(CSA_PWD)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/form/button').click()
element_to_hover = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a')
hover = ActionChains(driver=driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover)
hover.perform()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/nav/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a').click() # GWL compare
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listTable_length"]/label/select/option[5]').click() # show all entries
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listTable"]')
time.sleep(2)
for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
    for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td'):
        print(d.text)
```

and the output is as follows:

[image]

I would expect to see something similar with playwright.
I'm aware that I'm not iterating through content with playwright code (I'm not sure how to do that because when I use locator to select elements and try to put a for loop, it throws an exception that locator object is not iterable), this is the furthest that I was able to go.
I did try to follow the documentation of playwright [here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators#lists) without any success. If anyone has suggestions on how I could reach the data with playwright as I did with selenium, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter `slow_mo` is misleading. What you should have done was passing `'networkilde'` to your `page.wait_for_load_state()` like `page.wait_for_load_state('networkilde')` or use a [locator](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators)

For anyone referring to this in the future, `slow_mo` slows down the rendering which gives more time for the DOM to load data and it is just a debugging tool from [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/debug#run-in-headed-mode)

The accepted answer should not be used unless they are debugging their automation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by simply giving a `slow_mo=300` parameter to `launch()` function, so, the code of `browser` variable now looks like this:

```py
browser = p.chromium.launch(slow_mo=300)
```

I'm not sure if this helps anyone else, but it solved my issue.

Shocking.